# How to hide unused printers

Tags: 16.04, printing

Is there a simple way to hide printers from the printer dialog without uninstalling them?

My job implies having several working location, each with their own set of printers, where I stay for several days.

I have by now several printers installed (only 26 but I once had more than 100), many of them after a hard time to find the PPD and set it up properly.

I would need to "hide" the printers I am not using at the moment, without uninstalling them, in order not to have them always displayed in the printer dialog. Uninstalling them is not an option, especially for the ones that were really hard to set up on an Ubuntu box.

Actually, the best would be to be able to create groups of printers in order to switch the visibility of the whole group.

Example: Working on location 1, using printer A, B and C... I want to "hide" all other printers. Then, moving to working location 2, using printers C and D, I would like to hide all other printers... and so on.